# How to sort by date correctly with jQuery Plugin Data Tables

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables, date-sorting

I'd like to know how I can sort my tables by a date correctly.
I'm using jquery with the plugin Data Tables (http://datatables.net/).

I also found a useful plugin on this site for my problem, which I integrated into my code.
My JS-Code looks like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk_date-asc']  = function(a,b) {
    var ukDatea = a.split('/');
    var ukDateb = b.split('/');

    var x = (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
    var y = (ukDateb[2] + ukDateb[1] + ukDateb[0]) * 1;

    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0));
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk_date-desc'] = function(a,b) {
    var ukDatea = a.split('/');
    var ukDateb = b.split('/');

    var x = (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
    var y = (ukDateb[2] + ukDateb[1] + ukDateb[0]) * 1;

    return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ?  -1 : 0));
};

   var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumns": [
            null,
            { "sType": "uk_date" },
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
        ]
    } );


$(".search_init").click(function(){
    var input_value = $(this).val();
    $(this).val("");
});     

$("tfoot input").keyup( function () {
    oTable.fnFilter( this.value, $("tfoot input").index(this) );
} );

});
</script>
```

My table looks like this:

```
<table id="example">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Some Text</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Some Text</th>
        <th>Some Text</th>
        <th>Some Text</th>
        <th>Some Text</th>
        <th>Some Text</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Some text</td>
        <td>22/07/2011</td>
        <td>Some text</td>
        <td>Some text</td>
        <td>Some text</td>
        <td>Some text</td>
        <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="search_init" value="Text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="search_init" value="Text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="search_init" value="Text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="search_init" value="Text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="search_init" value="Text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="search_init" value="Text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="search_init" value="Text" /></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Could someone explain me why this isn't working?
I'm able to sort each column except the one with the dates in it.

I include following libraries:

```
<script src="[PATH]/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="[PATH]/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="[PATH]/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="[PATH]/js/ZeroClipboard.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="[PATH]/js/TableTools.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Found the solution.. a stupid mistake.
I used h2 tags to format my dates and didn't striped them in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in trying another plugin, here is a solution for the popular [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com) plugin that I've used in the past. Basically just use the plugin and create a custom parser for your dates.

Here is the date parser I created:

```
/*
* Parser Type: DateTime
* Parser Format: "ddd, MMM d, yyyy h:mm tt"
*/
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    // set a unique id
    id: 'LongDateTimeFormat',
    is: function (s) {
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s) {
        s = s.trim();

        // format your data for normalization
        s = s.match(/(?!^[A-Za-z]{3}, )[A-Za-z]{3} [0-9]{1,2}, [0-9]{4} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}/) + ":00 " + s.match(/[A-Z]{2}$/);

        return new Date(s).getTime();
    },
    // set type, either numeric or text 
    type: 'numeric'
});
```

The expected date format is "ddd, MMM d, yyyy h:mm tt" as indicated above. The parser converts the date string to a date object and returns the number of milliseconds since midnight of January 1, 1970 to the specified date.

Comment: Hey craig thank you for your proposition but I've already used tablesorter in the past but decided to change to dataTables which brings along much more functionality.. if it works..

Comment: @DamianFrizzi That's cool, I'll have to check it out then! Without looking at it, I wouldn't be surprised if you need to do something similar to tablesorter like create a parser so that the dates can be compared correctly.

Comment: @DamianFrizzi looks like a sweet plugin, will be trying that out next time. Thanks!

Comment: The functions I wrote in the code above should compare the listed dates and sort them.. No problem, have fun :)

Comment: @DamianFrizzi right, that is the syntax for creating custom parsers with this plugin. Regarding the datatable plugin, OOB a date column will only be sortable by default if it can be automatically detected by Date().parse(). So those parsers you have grabbed from the site should work. Is it possible the date format is not quite right?

Comment: I solved the problem but I couldn't answer my own question because I'm new to stackoverflow. I used h2 tags to format my dates and didn't striped them in JS.

Comment: @DamianFrizzi nice! that is was I was getting at when I mentioned the date format not being correct. Glad I attempted to answer this question though because the plugin does look decent form afar. Cheers

Comment: So I probably missunderstood you. My english isn't that good :) cheers

Comment: @DamianFrizzi no worries, thanks for introducing me to this plugin!

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me.

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
            "uk_date-pre": function (a) {       

          if (a!=""&&a!=null)
            {
              var date = a.split('/');
              var x= (Number(date[2]) * 10000 + Number(date[1]) * 100 + Number(date[0])) * 1;
              return x;
            }
            else return 0;
            },

            "uk_date-asc": function (a, b) {
                return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
            },

            "uk_date-desc": function (a, b) {
                return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write date in "YYYYMMDD" format inside   whose style is display none before date view.

### Example Code

```
<table id="example" class="table" width="100%" cellspacing="0" data-order='[[ 1, "asc" ]]' data-page-length='100'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Sl.No</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><span style="display:none;">YYYYMMDD</span>DD/MM/YYYY</td>
            <td>P K Jena</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td><span style="display:none;">YYYYMMDD</span>DD/MM/YYYY</td>
            <td>P Kumar</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```